# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload

In `_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@activity,:remote=>true, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :name %>

    <%= f.input :logo%>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

In `create.js.erb`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
<%if @activity.save %>
$('#divShow').html("<%= j (render 'activities/index') %>");
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
$('#notice').html("Activities is successfully created.").show();
<%else%>
$('.modal-body').html("<%= j (render 'activities/form') %>");
<%end%>
});
```

In `activities_controller`:

```
def create
@activity = Activity.new(activity_params)
@activity.save
end
```

In `logs` :

> Processing by ActivitiesController#create as HTML
>
> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "activity"=>{"name"=>"sds",
>   "logo"=>#,
>   @original_filename="1241112.png", @content_type="image/png",
>   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"activity[logo]\";
>   filename=\"1241112.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">},
>   "commit"=>"Create Activity"}
>
> Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
>
> Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms
>
> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

In the view page i am using `simple_form` gem and CURD operation with JS. But, i am getting error from file upload(:logo) while creating a new record.Please help me out,thanks.

Comment: Try adding `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }` to your `applicationscontroller`

Comment: It's a `Proc` class available bydefault, you can call is as procedure

Comment: In your controller create method, you can specify that `respond_to do |format|
    format.js 
    }
  end`

Comment: and add a file `create.js` in views

Comment: I am getting `ActionController::UnknownFormat` in `respond_to do |format|` and i have already `create.js.erb` file...plz see above

Comment: Try this, `def create
@activity = Activity.new(activity_params)
if @activity.save
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render(:text => "nil") }
  format.js
end end end`

Comment: try that, we are rendering nothing on `HTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `gem "remotipart"` to solve the issue:

1.Add `gem "remotipart"` to your gemfile.

2.Run `bundle exec rails g remotipart:install`.

3.Add `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` to the layout page.

4.Add `//= require jquery.remotipart` to the `application.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this in the activities_controller.rb put this on the top:

```
 skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create
```

Also you have to define templates, so the view will be:

```
def create
  @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @activity.save(activity_params)
      format.js {}  
    else
      format.js {}  
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: getting `ActionController::UnknownFormat` in line `respond_to do |format|` and also  `Processing by ActivitiesController#create as HTML
`

Comment: You try in view what I suggest in my answer? It should work without problem

Comment: I tested and your right. if you add this line before format.js =>         format.html { redirect_to @activity, notice: 'Activity was successfully created.' } will work but I need to figure out why dont get js format.

Comment: To be able to read js format you have to add <code> :format => :js </code> 'in simple_form_for line. I dont figure out why dont get :remote => true.